# Replacing a single character in a String

Tags: java

The issue is needing to replace a single character in a given string while maintaining the other characters in the string.

The code is:

```
    if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("replace single"))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the character to replace");
        String char2replace = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the new character");
        String secondChar = keyboard.nextLine();    
        System.out.println("Which " + char2replace + " would you like to replace?");
        int num2replace = keyboard.nextInt();

            for(int i=0; i< bLength; i++)
            {   

                if(baseString.charAt(i)== char2replace.charAt(0))
                {
                    baseString = baseString.substring(0, i) +
                            secondChar + baseString.substring(i + 1);

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it, just add a counter in your loop:

```
int num2replace = keyboard.nextInt();
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bLength; i++) {
    if (baseString.charAt(i) == char2replace.charAt(0)) {
        count++;
        if (count == num2replace){
            baseString = baseString.substring(0, i) +
                    secondChar + baseString.substring(i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (char2replace.length() > 1) {//you need move this out of loop
        System.out.println("Error you can only enter one character");
    }


}
System.out.println(baseString);
```

Comment: You are a freaking lifesaver. Thanks a million! :-)

Comment: your welcome :) , you can label answer like this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `command.replaceAll("and", "a")` for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder to replace a single character at some index, like this:

```
int charIndex = baseString.indexOf(charToBeReplaced);
StringBuilder baseStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(baseString);
baseStringBuilder.setCharAt(num2replace, secondChar);
```

Read more about StringBuilder's setCharAt() method [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt(int,%20char)).